# Which of the following function need not necessarily has limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $f(x)$ is a function such that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ exists,then which of the following function need not necessarily has limit?

$1.|f(x)-f(a)|$

$2.\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}$

$3.log(f(x))$

$4.e^{-f(x)}$

My attempt:I think $3$ option is the answer if it is base ten logarithmic,but for natural log this exists.What should be my answer and why?

Thanks.

Comment: I think 2 and 4 are obviously true,for 2 if limit is non-zero.

Comment: Should we have $f(x) > 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably these are all limits as $x \to a$?

If so, the main result you want to use is "if $g(y)$ is continuous at $L$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x\to a}g(f(x)) = g(L) = g\left(\lim_{x\to a} f(x)\right)$".

Given this, which of the above functions might *fail* to be continuous at $L$? (note this will depend on what $L$ is, so you should state the different cases for each). Further, you should worry a little about $f(a)$ in the first expression.

More detailed hints/answers:

> 1. $g(y) = |y - f(a)|$ is continuous for all $y$, provided $f(a)$ is defined (the limit exists, but the function may still be undefined).
> 2. $g(y) = \frac{\sin(y)}{y}$ is continuous, provided $y \neq 0$. So this limit exists if $L \neq 0$, otherwise it is possible it doesn't. However, the limit of $\sin(x)/x$ as $x \to 0$ is well-known and converges to $1$.
> 3. $g(y) = \log(y)$ is continuous for $y > 0$. So this limit exists if $L > 0$, otherwise it doesn't.
> 4. $e^{-y}$ is continuous for all $y$. So this limit always exists.
>
> Thus, 1 and 3 could all *fail* to have limits. 2 and 4 are the ones that are guaranteed.

Actually, more precisely, 1. could fail to be well-defined, if $f(a)$ is not defined. This is distinct from not having a limit. I wonder if the exercise wants you to explore this or not.

Comment: I disagree with your answer about #2... Please look at https://www.google.com/search?q=sin%28x%29+%2Fx&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=ssl#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=sin%28x%29%2Fx

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. I'll change it.

Comment: About 3,4 I understand sorry but other two not so much clear to me,can you give some counter example of first option?

Comment: If $f(a)$ is defined then first option is also true?

Comment: @BaronVT Oh sorry option 2 is also clear to me.

Comment: Yes, if $f(a)$ is defined, then the limit always exists, no matter what $L$ is.

Comment: The expression $f(a)$ might have no sense. Example: $f(x) = \frac {1} {x}$ when $a = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip: if the $f(x) \to 0$ what will happen with the $\log(f(x))$?

Comment: Hmm then limit will be infinity